# How to transform images in CSS while scrolling

Tags: html, css, animation

does anyone have any good tutorials on how to do this animation here: https://www.lyst.com/denim-report/ (DENIM letters moving and background is constant until word is formed).

I have tried searching but there are only tutorials for rotating images.

Thank you so much :)

Comment: You can find some useful information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate3d). This effect can be achieved with the combination of Javascript (scroll event) + CSS Transformation.

Comment: Check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/ramon82/pen/opJXGr) as well.